# How should we set a import path in solidity?

Tags: solidity, import, compilation

I failed to compile a solidity file with import statement.

> Error: Source not found: File not found.
>   import './contract.sol';

How should we set a import path?

I used web3.js for compiling.

> web3.eth.compile.solidity(data);

Layout of a Solidity Source File — Solidity 0.2.0 documentation
http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html

Comment: What happens if you use the absolute/full path, like `/home/nakanishi/lorem/contract.sol` ?

Comment: Use the normal compiler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files and paths are explained in detail here: http://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout-of-source-files.html

Key points:

**Paths**

In `import "filename";`, filename is always treated as a path with / as directory separator, . as the current and .. as the parent directory. Path names that do not start with . are treated as absolute paths.

To import a file x from the same directory as the current file, use import ”./x” as x;.

**Use in actual Compilers**

When the compiler is invoked, it is not only possible to specify how to discover the first element of a path, but it is possible to specify path prefix remappings so that e.g. `github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/library` is remapped to `/usr/local/dapp-bin/library` and the compiler will read the files from there. If remapping keys are prefixes of each other, the longest is tried first. This allows for a “fallback-remapping” with e.g. `“”` maps to `“/usr/local/include/solidity”`.