# How connect library to smart contract from external resources?

Tags: solidity

Now I connect library SafeMath.sol in local project.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
   import './ERC20.sol';
   import './SafeMath.sol';
```

How can I connect *SafeMath.sol* from external(non-local) resources or other contracts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using import statements you need to have the actual files of the imported contracts as well. In your case, ./SafeMath.sol specifies to the compiler that the contract you are importing is in the same directory with your own contract.

Please see more regarding import paths in : [How should we set a import path in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/how-should-we-set-a-import-path-in-solidity)

And in case you want to link your contract to a library:
[What are the steps to compile and deploy a library in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6927/what-are-the-steps-to-compile-and-deploy-a-library-in-solidity)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the development environment you are working with. This article explains everything about importing external code: https://blockheroes.dev/import-external-contracts-libraries/.

For Remix, you just go to OpenZeppelin's git repo and copy the URL and import it:

```
import “https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol”;
```

For Truffle, you have to install the package:

```
npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
```

and then import it in your code:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
```